# Replacing gamma at half integers by double factorial

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

It is well-known that for any positive integer $n$ the equality $\Gamma(n+\frac12)=\sqrt\pi\,(2n-1)!!/2^n$ holds, where $!!$ stands for the [double factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial). I am using `FullSimplify[expr,Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]` on certain expression `expr`, and the output contains $\Gamma(-\frac12+n)/\sqrt\pi$.

My question is: how can I instruct Mathematica to perform the simplification "$\Gamma(n+\frac12)=\sqrt\pi\,(2n-1)!!/2^n$ whenever $n$ is a positive integer" ? Of course, I want an answer no limited to this specific situation.

**Edit:** What I want is to "add" the simplification rule above to the list of simplifications included in `FullSimplify`, not merely "replace" the "string" $\Gamma(\cdots)$ by $\cdots !!/\cdots$.

Comment: you can simply do `expr/.Gamma[n+1/2]-> Sqrt[Pi](2 n-1)!!/2^n` and check!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a function to do this expansion for you:

```
ClearAll[gammaExpand]
gammaExpand[e_] := e /. (Gamma[n_ + 1/2 /; FullSimplify[n ∈ Integers && n > 0]] :> 
                         Sqrt[π] (2 n - 1)!!/2^n)
```

The `FullSimplify` in the definition takes care of picking up any assumptions placed in surrounding `Assumptions` blocks or assignments to `$Assumptions`.

```
expr = Sin[Log[Gamma[1/2 + n]]];
```

This doesn't expand (as it should):

```
gammaExpand@expr
```

> Sin[Log[Gamma[1/2 + n]]]

This does:

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers && n > 0, gammaExpand@expr]
```

> Sin[Log[2^-n Sqrt[π] (-1 + 2 n)!!]]

---

It would be nice if you could build this rule into `FullSimplify` itself. It has the option `TransformationFunctions` for that. However, there is a reason that this doesn't work:

```
FullSimplify[expr, 
            Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers && n > 0, 
            TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, gammaExpand}
]
```

> Sin[Log[Gamma[1/2 + n]]]

The reason is that the resulting expression is simply more complex than the original, so `FullSimplify` doesn't have an incentive to perform this step. In fact, whenever it sees anything like the expanded form it will try to reduce it:

```
FullSimplify[2^-n Sqrt[π] (-1 + 2 n)!!,
             Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers && n > 0]
```

> Gamma[1/2 + n]

You could try to come up with a modified version of the default `ComplexityFunction` but that would probably be too much hassle for this simple goal. Easier would be to forbid the reducing transformation using `ExcludedForms`:

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers && n > 0, 
   FullSimplify[expr // gammaExpand, 
                ExcludedForms -> {Sqrt[π] (2 n_ - 1)!!/2^n_}
   ]
]
```

> Sin[Log[2^-n Sqrt[π] (-1 + 2 n)!!]]

Comment: FWIW, `ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 100 Count[#, _Gamma, Infinity] &)` is suitable setting.  Also the pattern `Gamma[n_] /; FullSimplify[n - 1/2 \[Element] Integers && n > 1/2]` seems to work more generally.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I know, had been experimenting with that but noted that in Nasser's follow up question this was already provided, so didn't care to add that here. One big disadvantage would be that it would prevent any simplification with Gamma unrelated to the double factorial that is the issue here.

Comment: There's your +1.  I guess I should read comments before answering.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to define

```
Gamma[n_ + 1/2] := theExpression /; FullSimplify[ Element[ n, Integers ] && n > 0]
```

you will get

[image]

That is, you cannot "add the simplification rule above to the list of simplifications included in `FullSimplify`" without unprotecting Gamma first. The following code should do what you ask.

```
Unprotect[Gamma];
Gamma[n_ + 1/2] := theExpression /; FullSimplify[Element[n, Integers] && n > 0];
Assuming[Element[s, Integers] && s > 0, Gamma[1/2 + s]]
```

Nevertheless, exercise caution when unprotecting Mathematica definitions.