# How to select TransformationFunctions based on Assumptions made when using Simplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I am re-writing the question using a very simple example so not to confuse matters with the another question being asked where I used the example from there.

In general, how to add logic to switch between one `TransformationFunctions` or another inside `Simplify` or any function that uses  `TransformationFunctions`?

For example,

```
ClearAll[n, tf, e, cf];
cf[e_] := LeafCount@e
tfForIntegerOnly[e_] := If[MatchQ[e, 2 n], n, e]
tfForRealOnly[e_] := If[MatchQ[e, 2 n], n^2, e]

Assuming[Element[n, Integers], 
 Simplify[2 n, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}, ComplexityFunction -> cf]]
```

How to make it use `tfForIntegerOnly` when `Element[n, Integers]` and use `tfForRealOnly` when `Element[n, Reals]`

**Where to add this logic**? How to pass the assumptions around or check for it and what it contains? Since Mathematica does not have types (in traditional sense) associated or attached with the symbols themselves (other than looking at Head, which in this case provides no information), one needs a general way to handle this.

### Original question below

I'd like to simplify an expression under one set of assumptions using one `TransformationFunctions` function and use another `TransformationFunctions` function (or use `Automatic`) for different set of assumptions.

The problem is that the `TransformationFunctions` itself has no access to these `Assumptions` used before in calling `Simplify` and hence it is hard to find a way to add logic to detect which assumptions is used at that level.

To explain, I want to apply `TransformationFunctions` to transform `Gamma[1/2 + n]` to `Sqrt[Pi] (Factorial2[2 *(n - 1/2) - 1])/2^(n - 1/2)` but only when `Element[n, Integers] && n > 1`.

I am not able to find a way to pass these assumptions from the `Assuming` call to the `TransformationFunctions` or a way to make 2 different `TransformationFunctions` and use vs. the other inside `Simplify` itself.

Here an example

```
ClearAll[n, tf, e, cf];
cf[e_] := Count[e, Gamma, Infinity, Heads -> True] 1000 + LeafCount@e 
tf[e_] := If[MatchQ[e, Gamma[1/2 + n]],Sqrt[Pi] (Factorial2[2 *(n - 1/2) - 1])/2^(n - 1/2), e]

Assuming[Element[n, Integers] && n > 1,Simplify[Gamma[1/2 + n] + Gamma[1/3 + n], 
TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf},ComplexityFunction -> cf]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But now if I assume `n` is `Real`, I do not want to modify the code above, but I want the `TransformationFunctions` to automatically to detect this and in this case not apply this transformation rule or add some logic inside `Simplify` to use one `TransformationFunctions` vs. the other based on `Assumptions`

```
ClearAll[n, tf, e, cf];
cf[e_] := Count[e, Gamma, Infinity, Heads -> True] 1000 + LeafCount@e 
tf[e_] := If[MatchQ[e, Gamma[1/2 + n]], Sqrt[Pi] (Factorial2[2 *(n - 1/2) - 1])/2^(n - 1/2), e]

Assuming[Element[n, Reals], Simplify[Gamma[1/2 + n] + Gamma[1/3 + n], 
  TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}, 
  ComplexityFunction -> cf]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which is wrong since now `n` is not an integer now.

I'd like to be able to write

```
Assuming[Element[n, Reals], Simplify[Gamma[1/2 + n] + Gamma[1/3 + n],
TransformationFunctions ->Cases[Element[n, Reals], Automatic, Element[n, Integers] && n > 1,tf],
  ComplexityFunction -> cf]
 ]
```

But the above is not valid syntax.

---

Comment: see my answer on the [original question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30320/57).

Comment: I got in the same problem when dealing with the [original question too](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30317/8803). At the time, I noticed that `Assuming[n \[Element] Integers, n \[Element] Integers]` returns `n \[Element] Integers` but `Assuming[n \[Element] Integers, Simplify[n \[Element] Integers]]` returns `True`. Reading the manual, it says that `Assuming` is used only for certain functions (`Simplify`, `Integrate`, …)

Comment: And again, my answer can be used for that. Have you actually studied it? All you need is a different condition in the FullSimplify part. The condition can also be placed at the at of the rule if that's more convenient.

Comment: It is very easy to generalize my answer to any rule you like. Just use the same transformation function name name for all your rule based transformations and use function overloading by varying the condition `/;` part. Also, you haven't read my comment about the use of the global symbol `n`.

Comment: Btw, could you use the @ convention when replying? I'll be away for the rest of the night. Bye.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries sorry forgot the "@". Please feel free to answer this if you like, better to have the answer for a generic question in one place. I did read what you said about "n" and I did mention that in my other question. Putting this all in one complete answer will be better, that is why I asked this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a bit of trouble following the use of explicit (hard-coded) Symbols (`n`) in your transformation functions.  I assumed these were used only for the simple example and replaced them with patters in my code below.

- One issue that may be causing you trouble is that [`Integers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Integers.html) is a subset of [`Reals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reals.html) so you need to test for the subset rather than the superset.
- Since [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Simplify.html) is responsive to [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24Assumptions.html) and by extension [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Assuming.html) we can use it to check our [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html).

I believe you want something like this:

```
ClearAll[n, tf, e, cf];
cf[e_] := Count[e, Gamma, Infinity, Heads -> True] 1000 + LeafCount@e

tf[Gamma[1/2 + x_]] /; Simplify[x ∈ Integers] :=
  Sqrt[Pi] (Factorial2[2*(x - 1/2) - 1])/2^(x - 1/2)
```

Now:

```
Table[
  Assuming[Element[n, domain] && n > 1, 
    Simplify[Gamma[1/2 + n] + Gamma[1/3 + n],
      TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}, 
      ComplexityFunction -> cf]],
  {domain, {Integers, Reals}}
] // Column
```

> ```
> 2^(1/2 - n) Sqrt[π] (2 (-1 + n))!! + Gamma[1/3 + n]
>
> Gamma[1/3 + n] + Gamma[1/2 + n]
> ```

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to the method I linked to in my comment above?

Comment: @Sjoerd I suppose it is, but I didn't see it until now.  Whatever, I hope this helps the OP solve his problem.