# Simplifying conditional expressions using assumptions does not work

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions, conditional

I have a conditional expression

```
f[x_] := x /; x ∈ Reals
```

This works fine for normal numbers and symbols, e.g. `{f[1], f[Sin[4]], f[I], f[a]}` evaluates to `{1, Sin[4], f[I], f[a]}` as expected.

However, if I have an unknown number $b$ which I know to be real, I cannot get Mathematica to give  $f(b)=b$. I have tried

```
Simplify[f[b], Assumptions -> {b ∈ Reals}]
```

but this evaluates to `f[b]`.

Comment: You are mixing things used for representing mathematical concepts with programming constructs.  `;` is a programming construct: it just influences evaluation.  It is not meant o be used this way and `Simplify` won't (and shouldn't) operate on it. I tried to write an answer but then I realized that the real question is: what do you want to do here?  You can take a look at `ConditionalExpression` which *is* meant for representing a mathematical concept, but whether it is of use to you depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you mean, "`{f[1], f[Sin[4]], f[I], f[a]}` evaluates to `{1, Sin[4], f[I], f[a]}`?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, I meant that, I must have copy-pasted the wrong part. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for pointing out the difference between mathematics and programming constructs. I see it does work with `ConditionalExpression`, but as you may have guessed this was not my real problem, so I will try to figure out how to formulate my real question.

Comment: @Nikki After a few minutes thinking I am guessing this question is a duplicate of one of these: [(30312)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30312/121),
[(30322)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30322/121).  For example you could write `f[x_] /; Simplify[x \[Element] Reals] := "success!"` and then `Assuming[x \[Element] Reals, Simplify[f[x]]]` which should yield `"success!"`.  Does this work for you?

Comment: I do not think this question is now very useful to me or other users. It has upvotes though, so should I delete it?

Comment: You can edit your question rather than deleting, or delete, edit, and undelete.  Please first look at the Q&A's and example I gave above.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, that does exactly what I thought my expression would do. Could you write it as an answer?

Comment: Great.  However there is no need for an additional answer; this method has been posted to each of the two Q&A's linked in my comment above.

Comment: Actually, reviewing both of those questions again they each seem rather complicated.  I like the simplicity of this question and its potential answer.  I shall answer and see what the community wants to make of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are willing to use [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html), which acts by way of [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html), you can use an `$Assumptions`-aware [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) to achieve what I believe you want.  I shall use`"success!"` to illustrate that the definition is truly being used and not another transformation.

```
f[x_] /; Simplify[x ∈ Reals] := "success!"
```

Now:

```
Assuming[x ∈ Reals, f[x]]
```

> ```
> "success!"
> ```

How this works:

1. `Assuming` has the attribute [`HoldRest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldRest.html) which keeps `f[x]` unevaluated until:
2. `Assuming` temporarily changes the value of `$Assumptions` to include `x ∈ Reals`
3. `f[x]` is called and the condition `Simplify[x ∈ Reals]` is evaluated
4. `Simplify` uses the value of `$Assumptions` and determines that `x ∈ Reals` is `True`
5. The `Condition` passes and `f[x]` evaluates to `"success!"`

---

This question is arguably a duplicate of each of these:

- [Replacing gamma at half integers by double factorial](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30312/121)
- [How to select TransformationFunctions based on Assumptions made when using Simplify?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30322/121)

However in review neither question seemed as direct and simple as this one so I hesitated to close.

Comment: This is a little bit frustrating because the problem is simple and the solution is far from being trivial ... (because of the use of the use of `/;` with `Simplify` , because you have to use `Assuming` (and its `HoldRest` attribute), because `Simplify` or `Refine` won't do the job at least directly ... The only alternative I've found is to use `Block` and `$Assumptions` : `Block[{$Assumptions=Element[a,Reals]},Simplify[f[a]]]` or `Block[{$Assumptions=Element[a,Reals]},Refine[f[a]]]`.  Are there other ways ? (without using `/;` for example ?)

Comment: @SquareOne Well you could use `PatternTest` instead of `Condition` but I don't see that as an improvement per se.  Likewise your `Block` is simply reimplementing `Assuming`.  What exactly is your complaint?  Would defining `realQ = Simplify[# ∈ Reals] &;` and then `f[x_?realQ] := "success!"` be more pleasing to you?

Comment: `Refine` is more specific to this task than `Simplify`.