# Expanding/printing function with constrained arguments

Tags: function-construction, printing

Let's say you have a function

$ f(t) = t, \text{ for } t > 0,$

declared in Mathematica as

```
f[t_?(# > 0 &)] := t;
```

How do you print that function?

I have tried multiple options like

```
f[t]
FunctionExpand[f[t], t > 0]
f[t] /; t > 0
```

These return

```
f[t]
f[t]
f[t] /; t > 0
```

and not

```
t
```

or

```
t /; t > 0
```

Which is what I want.

Comment: Have a look at `Piecewise`.

Comment: Hm... I thought this seemed familiar.  I should have searched first.  Proposed duplicates: [(30312)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30312/121), [(72325)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72325/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible I would define the function using [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) or [`Refine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refine.html), then use [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html):

```
f[t_] /; Refine[t > 0] := t;

Assuming[t > 0, f[t]]
```

> ```
> t
> ```