# Applying rules to functions with non numeric arguments

Tags: replacement, rule

I am trying to do the following (it's a simplified version):

```
In[1]:= rulepositive = { f[a_?Positive]:> f[a] };
In[2]:= rulenegative = { f[a_?Negative]:> 0 };

In[3]:= $Assumptions = Elements[w,Positive];

In[4]:= f[w]/.rulepositive
In[5]:= f[w]/.rulenegative
```

where I expect

```
Out[4]:= f[w]
Out[5]:= 0
```

But it doesn't work. In words I want to apply a set of mapping rules in functions with non numeric arguments, which nevertheless have definite nature (e.g. Positive/Negative).
How could I do it?

Comment: Why you can't simply use [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)?

Comment: `f[a_]:=Piecewise[{{Unevaluated[f[a]],a > 0},{0, a < 0}}]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't follow *what you expect*, but you can use [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) to respect [`$Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html):

```
rulepositive = {f[a_] /; Simplify[Positive@a] :> 1};   (* modified from your example *)
rulenegative = {f[a_] /; Simplify[Negative@a] :> 0};

$Assumptions = {w > 0};

f[w] /. rulepositive
f[w] /. rulenegative
```

> ```
>  1
>
>  f[w]
> ```

```
$Assumptions = {w < 0};

f[w] /. rulepositive
f[w] /. rulenegative
```

> ```
>  f[w]
>
>  0
> ```

Reference:

- [Simplifying conditional expressions using assumptions does not work](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72325/121)

Answer (score 0):

Positive is not a set.

```
    ?? Positive
    (*Positive[x] gives True if x is a positive number.*)
```

Compare to

```
    ?? Integers 
    (*Integers represents the domain of integers, as in x∈Integers. *)
```

Besides, your expectations seem to be off. Why would you expect '0' out of `f[w]/.rulenegative`? Moreover, was zero (which is neither positive nor negative) considered in your logic?

In any case, the code below might help you. The basic idea is to assign the information to `w` instead. See `TagSetDelayed` help "f/:lhs:=rhs assigns rhs to be the delayed value of lhs, and associates the assignment with the symbol f."

```
   rulepositive = {f[a_?Positive] :> "yeah"};
   rulenegative = {f[a_?Negative] :> "bummer"};
   w /: Positive[w] = True;
   w /: Negative[w] = False;
   f[w] /. {{rulepositive}, {rulenegative}}
   (*{{"yeah"}, {f[w]}}*)
```

Comment: No, zero is not a case due to the nature of the problem. Also `w` shouldn't be fixed positive or negative