# Simplifying simple Sqrt inequality

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to get Mathematica to **Simplify**

```
Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 2
```

to

```
x^2 + y^2 < 4
```

Among other things I've tried based on other's questions and answers

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 2, {x, y} \[Element] Reals, ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount]
(* Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 2 *)

FullSimplify[Refine[Reduce[(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 2), (x | y) \[Element] Reals]],ComplexityFunction -> LeafCount]
(* -Sqrt[4 - x^2] < y < Sqrt[4 - x^2] *)
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: One isn't necessarily more simple than the other. In fact, I would prefer the former as it shows an Euclidean relationship. So `Simplify[]` is unlikely to do this for you.

Comment: Since `x` and `y` are real, just square both sides: `expr = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 2; expr2 = #^2 & /@ expr`

Answer (score 2):

It appears the Mathematica doesn't have a function to automatically `Simplify` a relational expression by squaring both sides.

However, one can accomplish this by providing a `TransformationFunction` to Simplify.

For example:

```
tf1[a_ < b_] := a^2 < b^2
Simplify[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 2, TransformationFunctions ->{tf1, Automatic}]
(* x^2 + y^2 < 4 *)
```

However, `tf1` only works for a `LessThan` relation.

```
Simplify[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] > 2, TransformationFunctions -> {tf1, Automatic}]
(* Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] > 2 *)
```

But this can be fixed by adding an `Alternatives` pattern of relations. (Learned from [Simplify equations with pattern assumptions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42607/simplify-equations-with-pattern-assumptions) )

```
relationOperators = Equal | Unequal | Greater | Less | GreaterEqual | LessEqual

tf2[l_~(relOp : relationOperators)~r_] := (l^2)~relOp~(r^2)

Table[Simplify[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]~op~ 2, TransformationFunctions -> {tf2, Automatic}], {op, Level[relationOperators, -1]}]

(* {x^2 + y^2 == 4, x^2 + y^2 != 4, x^2 + y^2 > 4, x^2 + y^2 < 4, x^2 + y^2 >= 4, x^2 + y^2 <= 4} *)
```

Additionally, TransformationFunction can be expanded to only apply under the `Condition` that operands are `Reals` or relation is `Equal` or `Unequal`. (Learned from [How to select TransformationFunctions based on Assumptions made when using Simplify?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30322/how-to-select-transformationfunctions-based-on-assumptions-made-when-using-simpl) )

```
tf3[l_~(relOp : relationOperators)~r_] /; Simplify[(l \[Element] Reals) && (r \[Element] Reals) || relOp == Equal || relOp == Unequal]  := (l^2)~relOp~(r^2)

Table[Simplify[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]~i~ 2, TransformationFunctions -> {tf3, Automatic}], {i, Level[relationOperators, -1]}]
(* {x^2 + y^2 == 4, x^2 + y^2 != 4, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] > 2, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 2, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] >= 2, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= 2} *)

Assuming[{x, y} \[Element] Reals, Table[Simplify[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]~i~ 2, TransformationFunctions -> {tf3, Automatic}], {i, Level[relationOperators, -1]}]]
(* {x^2 + y^2 == 4, x^2 + y^2 != 4, x^2 + y^2 > 4, x^2 + y^2 < 4, x^2 + y^2 >= 4, x^2 + y^2 <= 4} *)
```