# Is there a function equivalent to rewrite function in Sympy

Tags: simplifying-expressions, term-rewriting

Sympy provide `rewrite` function to rewrite expression in terms of other functions.

```
Rewrites expression containing applications of functions
of one kind in terms of functions of different kind. For
example you can rewrite trigonometric functions as complex
exponentials or combinatorial functions as gamma function.
```

This function can do something like following:

```
In [8]: atan(x).rewrite(asin)
Out[8]: (-asin(1/sqrt(x**2 + 1)) + pi/2)*sqrt(x**2)/x

In [9]: atan(x).rewrite(asec)
Out[9]: sqrt(x**2)*asec(sqrt(x**2 + 1))/x
```

For trigonometric function, here is a related question: [How to express trigonometric equation in terms of of given trigonometric function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/434/how-to-express-trigonometric-equation-in-terms-of-of-given-trigonometric-functio)

P.S.: Sympy actually writing these rewrite rules into the definition of the function.

Comment: You can try `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` with a customized `ComplexityFunction`. These surely know the rules you are interested in, but applying them in the desired fashion can be a bit tricky at times. `FunctionExpand`, `ExpToTrig`/`TrigToExp`, `ComplexExpand` can be useful in this to get a reasonable starting point offering many possibilities for simplification in the desired way.

Comment: @OleksandrR. generally, I think the answer for this question may be no. I think it is unlikely by using `Simplify` with `ComplexityFunction` can do this kind of job automatically. For example `FullSimplify[TrigToExp@ArcTan[x], 
 ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 
     100 Count[#, _ArcTan, Infinity] &)]` returns `ArcTan[x]` as well.

Comment: Well, not entirely. "rewrite trigonometric functions as complex
exponentials" is covered by `TrigToExp[]`, and "combinatorial functions as gamma functions" is done by `FunctionExpand[]`.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. rewriting `Gamma` is also tricky. `Assuming[n \[Element] Integers && n > 1, 
 FullSimplify[Gamma[n], 
  ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 
      100 Count[#, _Gamma, Infinity] &)]]` returns `Gamma[n]`. Same code for `Gamma[n + 1]` returns `n!`. [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30312/replacing-gamma-at-half-integers-by-double-factorial) is a related question.

Comment: Well, it's tricky with `FullSimplify[]`; not so much with `FunctionExpand[]`.